# Wordpress URL Change on submit

Tags: database, wordpress, url-rewriting, phpmyadmin

I currently have a website i'm working on that I have taken over from another individual, I dumped his SQL file into my database and everything seems to be ok apart from one thing. Whenever I try to log in to the back end or if I try to go elsewhere, it will add an additional .co.uk to the address bar, making it like so:

From: www.domain.co.uk to www.domain.co.uk.co.uk

I've had a dig in the database but I really can't find anything and i've never faced this issue before, could anyone shed some light on this for me? Maybe just let me know where I could look within the database to identify the problem, many thanks.

Comment: The url blog's is in the options Table. There are two records, one of them in the first rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the .htaccess file in the root folder, which is hidden and may contain rewrite rules.

Also, I recommend you use this plugin for migrations:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

I use it whenever I move from localhost to a live site and vice versa. It will also ensure your widgets are preserved, since doing a find replace will cause the object serialisation syntax WordPress uses to break.

After migrating, you need to visit Settings > Permalinks so the .htaccess file can be updated according to the new URL for rewrites.

Comment: That's awesome, problem is, I no longer have access to the original and working live copy because the person I took it from and myself no longer speak, and I cannot alter the settings due to not being able to access the back end at all

Comment: why can't you access the back end (wp-admin)?

Comment: Whenever I try to log in, it alters the URL to add a second .co.uk and whenever I remove this and try and submit the form again it asks for the log in information again

Comment: Remove the .htaccess file in the root directory so it doesn't rewrite